# String Truncate in C

Tags: c, python-3.x

```
def slicing(string, integer):
    original_str = string
    if len(string) <= integer:
        return 0
    elif len(string) > integer:
        string = string[:integer]
        num = len(original_str) - len(string)
        print(string)
        return num
```

Is there no str[] slicing function in C?

Comment: Correct. There is no function in C like `str[x:y]` in Python.

Comment: @immibis hmm, any idea how I could implement this in C then?

Comment: That isn't really how SO works. Show your attempt and describe your specific difficulties, then someone may be able to help you.

Comment: `strndup(str + x, y);`

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C are just null-terminated arrays of `char`s, so to start from the middle all you need to do is add an offset; `str[x:]` would just be `str + x`.

If you don't want to go all the way to the end of the string you'll need to copy the substring you're interested in; there is a `strndup()` function in POSIX 2008 which makes this trivial, just `strndup(str, length)`. Putting it together:

```
strndup(str + x, y);
```

I'm not sure if Windows has `strndup`, but if not it's quite easy to write your own. If you're using glib, there is a `g_strndup` function you can use.

Comment: Yeah. And it wouldn't let me do a 1 character edit. <shrug>

Answer (score 0):

String in C is somehow similar to string in python, that they are both immutable (meaning you can't modify the original string but need to make a copy first).

You can use `strdup` or `strcpy`to copy a string. The difference between these two is `strdup` will allocate the memory for you and you need to remember to free the memory after you are done with it.

With `strcpy`, you need to allocate the memory first (if you know the length) before you call it. You don't need to free the memory with `strcpy`.

Comment: This is completely wrong. Strings are absolutely mutable in C. String literals are a different matter, though.